# Gson: specify naming policy for class or field

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the misfortune to parse JSON data where different naming policies coexist.

```
{
  "camelCaseData" : {
    "someField" : 1
  },
  "snake_case_data" : {
    "some_field" : 2
  }
}
```

Is it possible to specify naming policy for the whole `snakeCaseData`? Or another solution that helps to avoid manual annotating of each field by `@SerializedName`?

Something like the following

```
class Data {
  CamelCaseData camelCaseData;

  @GsonNamingPolicy(com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES )
  SnakeCaseData snakeCaseData;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't get to exactly what you were asking for, but I think this might help you anyway. Basically this would require you to annotate any class that contains only snake-case fields, and any snake-case fields in classes that also contain camel-case fields.

First we define an annotation like you suggested:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface GsonNamingPolicy {
    FieldNamingPolicy value();
}
```

Then we would annotate the classes as I described above:

```
public static class CamelCaseData {
    int someField;
}

@GsonNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
public static class SnakeCaseData {
    int someField;
}

public static class Data {
    CamelCaseData camelCaseData;

    @GsonNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    SnakeCaseData snakeCaseData;
}
```

Finally we define a custom `FieldNamingStrategy`, which checks the field and its declaring class for our new annotation. If the annotation is present, the policy defined in the annotation is used, otherwise it just uses a default policy.

```
public static class AnnotationFieldNamingStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy {
    public String translateName(Field field) {
        Class<?> declaringClass = field.getDeclaringClass();

        GsonNamingPolicy fieldNamingPolicy = field.getAnnotation(GsonNamingPolicy.class);
        GsonNamingPolicy classNamingPolicy = declaringClass.getAnnotation(GsonNamingPolicy.class);

        FieldNamingPolicy policy = FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY;

        if (fieldNamingPolicy != null) {
            policy = fieldNamingPolicy.value();
        } else if (classNamingPolicy != null) {
            policy = classNamingPolicy.value();
        }

        return policy.translateName(field);
    }
}
```

You can then use this strategy when configuring Gson:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingStrategy(new AnnotationFieldNamingStrategy())
            .create();

    Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

    System.out.println(data.camelCaseData.someField);
    System.out.println(data.snakeCaseData.someField);
```

This is not exactly what you were asking for, but hopefully it helps you anyway. I don't believe there is a way to check whether a field is annotated at a level beyond the class that declared it. It's possible there is a way to achieve what you are looking for, but it may require working with a custom `TypeAdapter` or `TypeAdapterFactory`.